# Eiffel failure on OS X - Eiffel cannot find library

Tags: eiffel

I use macOS Catalina, and installed EiffelStudio per instructions on the EiffelStudio install page. When I executed `estudio` on the command line, I got this error

```
$ estudio
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libgthread-2.0.0.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/Eiffel_19.05/studio/spec/macosx-x86-64/bin/estudio
Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Could someone help me with a solution?

Comment: Did you install MacPorts?
Then you can do `sudo port install eiffelstudio`

Comment: I did get EiffelStudio installed, but get this when executing estudio on the command line:
EiffelVision application could not launch, check DISPLAY environment variable - is DISPLAY set by Eiffel?

Comment: Is https://www.xquartz.org/ installed?.

Comment: Check this (https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/Support/Self-Help-Tools/Help-Articles/Help-Articles-Detail/ArtMID/10220/ArticleID/23855/Installing-or-Reinstalling-XQuartz-if-Upgrade-to-macOS-1015-Catalina-Causes-Issues) for issues with macOS Catalina and XQuartz

Comment: Followed your advice and reinstalled Xquartz, and EiffelStudio (thru Xcode) does come up with a welcome screen -- funny thing is that the buttons are not always labeled, and some of the panels seem filled with random colored patterns.

Comment: Oops- I meant Xquartz, not Xcode.

Comment: Does it happens with 19.05 and also 19.12?

Comment: I've only tried 19.05 -- have not installed 19.12. Has 19.12 fixed any bugs?

Comment: I would suggest submitting a report problem https://support.eiffel.com/